# iOS Simulator failed to install application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

My Xcode project started to give  "iOS Simulator failed to install the application"

I'm using iOS Simulator 7.1. The simulator runs any other project.
I've read other entries in stack overflow and 
I've tried to delete ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator from terminal,
reset from "iOS Simulator/Reset Content and Settings" menu,
shutdown and restart Maverick 
but result was the same.

Help please!

Update:
When I try to upload my application to a real device I got this error: "Could not inspect the application package."

I think this error is related to above error.

When I check system.log entries I found below lines:

```
...

05/05/14 00:04:48,507 Xcode[1534]: AMDeviceSecureTransferPath (thread 0x10bd96000): disableDelta: FALSE
05/05/14 00:04:48,606 Xcode[1534]: AMDeviceSecureTransferPath (thread 0x10bd96000): Using delta for package at path    file:///Users/serkan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-efvftyvllnqdibctwpfggqgjpfzk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.app/ ID is myapp.myapp
05/05/14 00:04:48,640 Xcode[1534]: AMDeviceStartHouseArrestService (thread 0x10bd96000):  There was an error from the device: ApplicationLookupFailed
05/05/14 00:04:48,650 Xcode[1534]: AMDeviceSecureTransferPath (thread 0x10bd96000): AMDeviceSecureTransferPath:1589 starting delta_transfer_directory, ref_afc: 0x0
05/05/14 00:04:50,642 Xcode[1534]: AMDeviceSecureTransferPath (thread 0x10bd96000): AMDeviceSecureTransferPath:1592 finished delta_transfer_directory
05/05/14 00:04:50,716 Xcode[1534]: call_and_response (thread 0x10bd96000): GOT AN ERROR 0xe8000051
05/05/14 00:04:50,716 Xcode[1534]: perform_command (thread 0x10bd96000): There was an error communicating with the service agent: 0xe8000051
05/05/14 00:04:50,717 Xcode[1534]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication (thread 0x10bd96000): Old style install failed for (PublicStaging/myapp.app)
05/05/14 00:04:50,717 Xcode[1534]: AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication (thread 0x10bd96000): Could not install package on device: kAMDPackageInspectionFailedError
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a folder named Resource or Resources? Rename that to a different name and try again. (Remember to clean the project.)

EDIT: If this does not fix it, look at the project settings, there under "Build phases" and there under "Copy Bundle Resources". Maybe a stale entry sits there and needs to be removed manually.

EDIT: Also clean the project. Hold the option key when clicking on the menu entry so it says "Clean Build Folder...". If necessary, remove the derived data: Open Organizer, select your project: There is an entry "Derived Data" which shows the path to the files generated by Xcode. Right to that is also a Delete button - click that to delete all the derived data. (Xcode will have to rebuild index files etc., nothing critical)

(I remember, that I saw such errors when I had a Resource(s) folder and when I renamed it, it worked again. As far as I understood, Resource is used for Mac OS X apps. I assumed it would not be used for iOS, but at least it caused trouble in my case.)

Comment: What other folder names do you use? (Also: Did you hold the option key so it says "Clean Build Folder..." and not just "Clean"?)

Comment: You should go to the build files: Open the Organizer, select Projects and there select your project. There's an entry for "Derived Data" with a little arrow button to the right of the path. Click that and a Finder is opened at that location. There go to Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ . There is your app. Make the Finder show the package content. What is there?

Comment: Yes, there are Pod libraries and myapp.app

Comment: There is a Resources directory in it

Comment: I'd suggest to remove the myapp.app there - and then build and try again

Comment: I've removed the app file and run again but I got same  "iOS Simulator failed to install the application." error

Comment: In your Xcode project settings select the "Build phases" in the top line and see whether there are still "Resource" entries in the "Copy Bundle Resources" list. If there are any, select it and remove it from the list with that little "-" button.

Comment: One of my Pod libraries (StarRatingControl) has a Resources folder. I remove that pod and problem solved. Thank you Rainer.

Comment: Thanks - glad it worked out. I'll add the Build phases part to the answer.

Comment: I removed this pod before but I didn't clean the build folder as you  said so that I couldn't realise the solution. Please add the cleaning part to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved for me by deleting:

`~/Library/Application Support/iPhoneSimulator`

folder and re-installing `xcode`.