# Resources in subfolder is not being included into ipa

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I have `Resources` folder where I have `images`, `sfx` and many other sub folders with lots of different resources. While running the app the resources that are in subfolders they cannot be found in iOS simulator, whereas the resources that are in `Resources` folder they are here:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/4BE3ED44-1E37-4CFF-A779-2D674146F5D3/HappyBoat iOS.app/
```

How to ask Xcode to pack resources in subfolders into .ipa too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a folder full of resources to a project select the

> File / AddFiles to "HappyBoat" ...

menu item, then highlight the folder that you want to add, and click "Create folder references for any added folders"

[image]

Comment: This could work, but in this case iOS simulator cannot install the app. And nothing helps. Clearing simulator files, project, nothing... Tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932750/ios-simulator-failed-to-install-the-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449041/ios-simulator-failed-to-install-application

Comment: That second link indicates that the name "Resources" is not allowed. I would reset the simulator per the first link, then delete the project from organizer, close Xcode, rename your existing project directory, start a new project, and then add all the files back into the new project. Note that you can use Finder to copy the source files (including .xibs and .storyboards) from the corrupted project to the fresh project.

Comment: I have found a way. Just added Resources folder with "Create groupse for any added folders", removed all the content, and re-added the content with "Create folder references for any added folder". Is installed in simulator and also found the resources as you have pointed out.

Comment: That's a good method. Good to hear that you got it to work :)